# Create HotKey inside a function (AutoHotKey)

Tags: function, scripting, key, autohotkey

So, I want my function to create a HotKey and returns the corresponding text of the hotkey when i press
here is my code below

```
global Object := {a:[1,"a","alexa"],b:[2,"b","battle"]}
global key_var1 :="!a"
global key_var2 := "!b"
create(key)
{
    HotKey, %key%, myKey
    return
        myKey:
            MsgBox, % Object.key[3]
    return
}

create(key_var1)
create(key_var2)
```

The issue here is, when i press the hotkey, the message box displays nothing just empty.
When i press the HotKey the message box must display the corresponding text inside my Object array (text is in position 3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Displays associative array element keyed to current hotkey:**

```
global Object := {"!a":[1,"a","alexa"], "!b":[2,"b","battle"]}
global key_var1 := "!a"
global key_var2 := "!b"
create(key)
{
    HotKey, %key%, myKey
    return
        myKey:
            MsgBox, % A_ThisHotkey ":" Object[A_ThisHotkey][3]
    return
}

create(key_var1)
create(key_var2)
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: [`IniWrite`](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/IniWrite.htm), [`IniRead`](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/IniRead.htm) and [`IniDelete`](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/IniDelete.htm)

Comment: Yeah it worked thanks but how can i read all the key-value pairs in .ini file into an object in my script.
Removing the key while reading .ini file returned the whole section
is there a way i can put all the key-value pairs into an object? (object which has a key and a value)